# PowerBuilder - PBDBMS - Database Profile setup - ORACLE 9

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, powerbuilder

currently We are using the PowerBuilder 9 and Oracle 9 - Problem in setting the database profile for Oracle 9. The PBDBMS is not available in Connection tab on Database profile setup - Oracle 9.

Datawindow - datasource using the Oracle stored procedure and also the procedure using the package PBDBMS.PUT_LINE().

But the same thing is available on Database profile setup - Oracle 7.3.

Is there any other option for PBDBMS or how can we get the PBDBMS on Database profile setup - Oracle 9 on PowerBuilder Database painter?. Or do we need install some other software to get the PBDBMS.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PBDBMS is obsolete and is not supported by the Oracle 9 driver. If you want to use the Oracle 9 driver you will need to modify your stored procedures to use Ref Cursors.

Comment: I am new to that Ref cursor can any body give some example of Refcursor in storedprocedure

Comment: But the same PBDBMS is working in PowerBuilder 9.0 and Oracle 9i, I didn't know how it is possible.

Is this possible?